# What was a "Qua" in a "Subsidy of Armour" in 1590?

Tags: weapons, 16th-century

The Archbishop of Canterbury [decreed](https://archive.org/stream/publicationslinc23lincuoft#page/n47/mode/2up) in 1590 that clergy should provide men and armour for the defence of the realm against the King of Spain. Clergy in the diocese of Lincoln had a "Subsidy of Armour" recorded by the diocese then later [published](https://archive.org/stream/publicationslinc23lincuoft#page/144/mode/2up) by the Lincoln Record Society.

A note in that record says

> The items enumerated are lances, light horses, petronels (ie large pistols used especially by horsemen), muskets, corslets, calivers (ie light muskets or harquebuses), bows, bills and halberds

However, quite a few of the clergy provided "A Qua:" (the colon indicating abbreviation) and that doesn't match anything in the note. A "[Quarrel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossbow_bolt)" seems a rather tiny donation compared to a light horse, so seems unlikely.

- **What was a "Qua:" in this list?**

**Update**
One page in that list spells a Qua-word in full:

[image]

- **Was "Qua" an abbreviation for "Qualiuer", and is that an alternative spelling of ["caliver"?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caliver)**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Look at your [same document](https://archive.org/stream/publicationslinc23lincuoft#page/n17/mode/2up/search/qua) , pg viii(pdf page 18), which defines the abbreviations used. Qua is listed as

> the equipment of a man armed with a caliver or harquebus.
>   [image]

Comment: I hunted all through that book for that abbreviation before posting here :-( Well done and thank you!

Comment: No problem. Thanks for bringing up an interesting document.

Comment: Well spotted. Looks like you beat me to the punch. :)

Comment: @sempaiscuba Yep, snuck one in.  Do you suppose many of these old texts have been indexed for genealogical research?  I see a lot of surnames here.

Comment: @user2448131 I'd say it's a work in progress. A lot have been indexed in the last 5 years or so, but even that has only scratched the surface of what is actually out there. A couple of years back I was told that one of the midlands county archives (possibly Wolverhampton?) had completed surname indexes for almost 15% of their collection, and that was one of the best indexed collections in the UK. And then there are all the collections in private hands ...

Answer (score 1):

It is probably the abbreviation for a "caliver" - a type of [arquebus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arquebus)

---

UPDATE:

I just found an online copy of the [Subsidy of Armour](https://archive.org/stream/publicationslinc23lincuoft#page/144/mode/2up), published by the Lincoln Record Society. In it, the items enumerated are listed in a footnote. A "Que". is indeed a caliver in this context.